# Learning Python: If condition executing all the time

Tags: python

I am learning python and i can't figure out why the following program is printing **your number is greater than what i thought** even when the guessed number is smaller. is it like in python, it is comparing strings rather the numbers ?

```
number = 32
tries = 1

print "I have chosen a number, you have to guess it."
guess = raw_input ("Guess:")

while guess != number:
    tries = tries+1
    if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is greater than i thought")
        guess = raw_input ("Another Guess:")
    else:
        print("Your guess is smaller than i thought")
        guess = raw_input ("Another Guess:")

print "You guess it right in %d turns." %tries
```

P.S:I know its a dumb question but i am a noob at python!

Comment: Yes, comparing strings rather than numbers won't do, because e.g. `'10' < '9'` since `'1' < '9'`.

Comment: What are the inputs you are trying? Please be more specific as to what you are trying, what your expected result is in each case, and what you are getting instead. Also, if the issue is string comparison, I highly doubt `guess > number` will ALWAYS be true-- see if you can find cases where it isn't true, and then you will understand more about what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't know this until just now, but as it turns out, a string will always be "greater than" an integer in Python:

```
>>> "0" > 1
True
```

All you need to do is replace

```
guess = raw_input ("Guess:")
```

with

```
guess = int(raw_input ("Guess:"))
```

Comment: I think I remember reading somewhere that if all else fails, Python simply compares the type names for determining the result of comparison checks: that is, since "string" comes after "int" (or "integer" or "number" or what have you), that explains why `"0" > 1` is `True`. (Note: When I say "if all else fails", I mean if type coercion fails in both directions)

Comment: Note: Python 3 causes a type error when comparing uncomparable values like int-str.

Comment: And it should! I'm surprised something so silly survived in Python for so long...

Comment: Does that mean Python 3 causes an error if you try to sort a list with mixed types in it?

Comment: @neil: Yes, it does. What else could it (reasonably) do? (Note that if you're talking instances of user-defined classes, you can always make them support comparison with objects of different types).

Answer (score 11):

`raw_input` will return a string. You need to parse it into a number for the compare to work properly. I think that's just `int(raw_input(...))`

Comment: It may be good to wrap a `try` `except` around the `int()` in case the input isn't numeric.

Answer (score 2):

Catching an exception might help as well if you are guessing a large number and you accidentally hit a letter you don't really want your program to bail out.

```
while guess != number:

    if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is greater than i thought")

    else:
        print("Your guess is smaller than i thought")
    try:    
        guess = int(raw_input ("Another Guess:"))
        tries = tries+1
    except ValueError:
        print "Input must be numeric"
print "You guess it right in %d turns." %tries
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because raw_input is considered a string, so Python assigns it a value based on the char values. Try writing int(raw_input("text")) and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here datatype of guess is string where as datatype of number is integer,

```
guess = raw_input ("Guess:")
```

so both are not same, hence if statement is executed every time

```
if guess > number:
```

as string datatype is considered greater than integer datatype in python.

Therefor you need to change the datatype of guess to int.

Following code will help you do this

```
guess = int(raw_input ("Guess:"))
```